# Why the projection formula of $x$ onto $v$ is given by $\frac{\langle x,v\rangle}{\langle v,v\rangle}v$?

Tags: geometry, soft-question, inner-products

Can somebody explain the formula for the projection of a vector $x$ onto a vector $v$?

The formula is given by $\frac{(x,v)}{(v,v)}v$.

Thanks!

Comment: basically, is take the cosine

Comment: more details completely drawn out appreciated... I'm new to math!!

Comment: I'm doing a plot, please wait

Comment: What exactly needs explaining? Do you not understand the notation (e.g. the inner products) or how to derive the formula?

Comment: derive the formula would help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image]

Given the vector $x$, you can see that the projection of $x$ in the direction of $v$ is just the component parallel to $v$.

To find this vector, we need the direction and the module:

**Find the direction:**

The direction is the same of $v$, so we can take a unit vector $\frac{v}{\|v\|}$

**Find the length:**

The length is geometrically the same as the component of $x$ given by cosine.
Length  = $\|x\|\cdot \cos(\theta)$

What is $\theta$ ? It's the angle between those vectos. **How do we calculate it?** with the inner product:
$$\langle x, v\rangle = \|x\|\cdot\|v\|\cos\theta$$

So, finally the vector is :
$$\operatorname{Proj}_vx = \text{length}\cdot\text{direction} = \|x\|\cdot \cos(\theta) \cdot \frac{v}{\|v\|}$$
$$ = \|x\|\cdot \frac{\langle x, v\rangle}{\|x\|\cdot\|v\|}  \cdot \frac{v}{\|v\|}  $$

Since $\|v\||^2 = \langle v,v\rangle$ :

$$\operatorname{Proj}_vx = \frac{\langle x,v \rangle \cdot v}{\|v\|^2} = \frac{\langle x,v \rangle \cdot v}{\langle v,v\rangle} $$

Comment: $||x|| \times \cos (\theta)$? You take the cross product here?

Comment: No, it is just a multiplication. I'll correct the typo for no more mistakes. I preffer use `\times`, than `\cdot`

Comment: remember that if $\times$ needs two vectors, if one side of the $\times$ operation is a scalar, then it just means a multiplication

Answer (score 2):

By definition, the projection of $v$ along $w$, where $w\neq 0$, is the vector $p = \alpha w$ such that $\langle v - p,w\rangle = 0$. Based on it, one has that
\begin{align*}
\langle v-p,w\rangle = \langle v - \alpha w,w\rangle = 0 & \Longleftrightarrow \langle v,w\rangle - \alpha\langle w,w\rangle = 0 \Longleftrightarrow \alpha = \frac{\langle v,w\rangle}{\langle w,w\rangle}
\end{align*}
and we are done. Hopefully this helps.

Comment: How do we know $p$ is unique?

Comment: @HerbEnthusiast the orthogonality condition ensures uniqueness.

Comment: What are the conditions that require $p=\alpha w$ to exist??

Comment: @HerbEnthusiast All scalar multiples of a vector are in the vector space. It's one of the vector space axioms.

Comment: I mean conditions that $p$ exists so as to make $\langle v-p,w \rangle=0$

Comment: $p$ is constructed to meet this condition. If you don't normalize the vector $v$ it will not be an orthogonal projection, and will instead be a skew projection which need not be unique.